# mysql "no packages marked for update" in Centos

Tags: centos, mysql

From the following guide i have been trying to update mysql on my Centos server:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/updating-yum-repo.html

My current mysql version is:

```
programversion: 5.1.73 - Source distribution
```

When i run the commands i get the following:

```
[root@****~]# sudo yum update mysql-community-release
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.fysik.dtu.dk
 * extras: mirror.fysik.dtu.dk
 * updates: mirror.fysik.dtu.dk
 * webtatic: nl.repo.webtatic.com
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00
webtatic                                                 | 3.6 kB     00:00
Setting up Update Process
No Match for argument: mysql-community-release
No package mysql-community-release available.
No Packages marked for Update
[root@*****~]# sudo yum update mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.fysik.dtu.dk
 * extras: mirror.fysik.dtu.dk
 * updates: mirror.fysik.dtu.dk
 * webtatic: nl.repo.webtatic.com
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
[root@*****~]# sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.fysik.dtu.dk
 * extras: mirror.fysik.dtu.dk
 * updates: mirror.fysik.dtu.dk
 * webtatic: nl.repo.webtatic.com
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

As you can see:

```
No Packages marked for update
```

So what can i do to upgrade my mysql version?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have MySQL's yum repository installed. As the directions advised you, you need to do that first.

Comment: i Read that you have to update to 5.5 before updateing to 5.6 but i can't seem to find the Yum repo that i need to install